# React parent send data to multiple children

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I have a react app with the above structure, where a parent has a sidebar and renders two children: Content and Rightbar.

When a link in the parent is clicked, I need to update both the Content and Rightbar sections.

Here is part of the code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRedirect to="/select" />
            <Route path="/select" component={Select}>
                <Route path="foo" component={Foo} />
                <Route path="bar" component={Bar} />
                <Route path="baz" component={Baz} />
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
, destination );
```

Inside the Select class:

```
        <div className="sidebar">
                <Link to="select/foo">Foo</Link>
                <Link to="select/bar">Bar</Link>
                <Link to="select/baz">Baz</Link>
        </div>

        <div className="content">
            {this.props.children}
        </div>

        <div className="rightbar">
            // I want to render a component here, but this.props.children can only contain one children
        </div>
```

Any solution to solve this, or possibly a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With React Router you can use multiple components like

```
<Route path="/foo" components={{content: FooContent, rightbar: RightBarComponent}}/>
```

Read for [Multi Named Components](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#named-components)